# TabControl and ObservableCollection UI Refresh

Tags: user-interface, grid, refresh, observablecollection, tabcontrol

I'm becoming crazy i don't understand why my ObservableCollections have a strange behaviour. I have  tabs :

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1">
    <TabControl Grid.Row="1">
        <TabItem Header="Posts instagrams">
            <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding InstagramPhotos, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Shop">
            <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ShopPhotos, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Articles">
            <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ArticlePhotos, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

The ObservableCollections are defined like this :

```
private ObservableCollection<PhotoModel> _instagramPhotos;
public ObservableCollection<PhotoModel> InstagramPhotos
{
    get => _instagramPhotos ?? (_instagramPhotos = new ObservableCollection<PhotoModel>());
    set
    {
        _instagramPhotos = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("InstagramPhotos");
    }
}

private ObservableCollection<PhotoModel> _shopPhotos;
public ObservableCollection<PhotoModel> ShopPhotos
{
    get => _shopPhotos ?? (_shopPhotos = new ObservableCollection<PhotoModel>());
    set
    {
        _shopPhotos = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("ShopPhotos");
    }
}

private ObservableCollection<ArticleModel> _articlePhotos;
public ObservableCollection<ArticleModel> ArticlePhotos
{
    get => _articlePhotos ?? (_articlePhotos = new ObservableCollection<ArticleModel>());
    set
    {
        _articlePhotos = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("ArticlePhotos");
    }
}
```

I bind commands for adding/update/delete element in each collections. The update work fine on every UI. BUT where it's strange is that the Add event works correctly in first tab but delete doesn't. And in other tab, add event doesn't work but delete works. I clearly don't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

FINALLY found out ! I was using this

```
DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource DataViewModel}}"
```

So it doesn't update. I put it in `<Window.DataContext>` tag and works well